# Bootstrap navbar search outside collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navbar with my brand on the left, a full-width search bar in the middle, and some other pages on the right.
When the page is viewed on a smaller screen I want the search bar to be in the same place, full-width, outside the collapse menu.

I'm having problems with getting the search bar full-width without pushing my pages on the right onto another row, and I also can't get the search bar on the same row when the page is in mobile format.

This is how it looks with a small screen size:

[image: This is how it looks with a small screen size]

This is the code for the navbar I am using, and the CSS is just default bootstrap 3.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <span>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
                </div>

                <form class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
                            <div class="input-group" style="display:table;">
                                <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>

            </span>
            <span>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li id="userPage">
                            <a href="#@userpage"><i class="icon-user"></i> My Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#logout" data-prevent="">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Here is a jsfiddle with my code so far on it.](http://jsfiddle.net/y4m529ff/)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you-

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
  <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
   <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It's similar, but I want the search box outside of the collapsible menu when the screen is smaller.